# What is the best overclock for Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti using Nvidia Inspector?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, overclocking

One of my friends has an old rig w/ ancient 750 Ti in it. To help him get a little extra power out of that dinosaur I've tried some overclocking on the card. I've done some research online and found some configurations which help, but am curious if there's any way to go further, or if there's someone else out there who knows what the approx. "max" is. Most of the reviews I found started comparing specs to the reviewer's own rig, which had (a) much more powerful card(s). Also, since it's an older rig, I don't want to do too much experimentation for fear of ruining the old hardware (which would make a great excuse for upgrading, but I don't want to that to him [just yet]).

Comment: Unless you go liquid cooling you are not going to get any sort of overclocking worth while on air cooling.  You are at best going to get 1-3 fps boost by overclocking the hardware you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the rest of the setup, you can't just assume because someone else increased their clock by 20% you can do the same. It depends on factors including but not limited to air flow around the GPU, the capability of the GPU fan to remove heat quickly, the amount of power the PSU can dish out, cooling within the case itself.

You best bet is to add a small incremental change to the GPU settings, then benchmark using something like 3DMark to see if the overclock is stable. Keep going up until you start to see tearing, artefacts or general video issues, then go back a little bit from there.